# Inserting a mini-array into a larger array at intervals (not changing size)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert

I'm trying to insert a mini array into a larger array without resizing, so changing the values of the larger array with the mini array.

Have a mini array, x*x.
Have a larger array, X*X
Every Y elements, replace the next elements with mini array values.
All the way till the end.

I've tried to do it through indexing (code can be found below).

```py
mesh_array = np.zeros(shape=(100,100), dtype=np.uint8) 
mini_square = np.ones(shape=(2,2), dtype=np.uint8) 

flattened_array = np.ravel(mesh_array) 
flattened_minisquare = np.ravel(mini_square) 

flattened_array[1:-1:10] = flattened_minisquare
```

Expected result is that every 10 elements, it will replace the following ones with the flattened_minisquare values.

```py
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0...]
```

The error message that I get:

```py
"ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (1000)"
```

Comment: Demonstrate what inserting  a (2,2) into a (10,10) would look like

Comment: That's the expected result of what I'm trying. Something similar to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better ways, but one way is to approach this problem as follows:

```
import numpy as np

mesh_array = np.zeros(shape=(100,100), dtype=np.uint8) 
mini_square = np.ones(shape=(2,2), dtype=np.uint8) 

flattened_array = np.ravel(mesh_array) 
flattened_minisquare = np.ravel(mini_square)
```

Now, we can construct array which would correspond to the positions where you wish to fill the `minisquare` with the remaining values as zeros. Note that it would, if the given output is correct, be an array of length 13 in this case. 9 elements of original array + 4 from the minisquare

```
stepsize = 10
temp = np.zeros(stepsize + len(flattened_minisquare) - 1)
temp[-len(flattened_minisquare):] = flattened_minisquare
```

We also create a mask for the values which are not filled by the minisquare.

```
mask = np.copy(temp)
mask[-len(flattened_minisquare):] = np.ones_like(flattened_minisquare)
mask = ~mask.astype(bool)
```

Now, just use `np.resize` to expand both the mask and the temp array, and then finally use the mask to fill the values back from the old array.

```
out = np.resize(temp, len(flattened_array))
final_mask = np.resize(mask, len(flattened_array))
out[final_mask] = flattened_array[final_mask]

print(out)
#[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I wanted but that also works nicely. Thanks a lot, have a good day

Comment: @DenisD If you wish to, you can clarify what you'd like instead. If that is sufficiently different from the example output posted here, you can post another question too. There is no obligation on you to accept an answer if it is not useful for you. What exactly did you want to do?

Comment: Well that is also useful for me, I ended up figuring out what I wanted. It's very unpythonic though. Here is what I initially wanted, but when I saw your solution, that was acceptable as well.

```python
x_axis = 11
y_axis = 15
test_array = np.zeros(shape=(x_axis, y_axis), dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(1, x_axis, 2):
    for j in range(1, y_axis, 2):
        test_array[i, j] = 1
print(test_array)
```

Comment: ah i see. Good job figuring out a workable solution though, glad to hear!